Customizing the default Sitemap.xml functionality in DXA 2.2.x (Java) by extending the getXmlSitemap() method not working
I am trying to create a custom Sitemap page that would override the default Sitemap.xml implementation in DXA. Here is the default Sitemap implementation
https://github.com/RWS/dxa-web-application-java/blob/DXA_2.3.3/dxa-framework/dxa-common-api/src/main/java/com/sdl/webapp/common/controller/SiteMapXmlController.java
Here is the method I am trying to extend as it says in the comments.
@NotNull
/**
 * This method is supposed to be extended in order to change the default behavior.
 */
public String getXmlSitemap() throws NavigationProviderException {
    SitemapItem model = navigationProvider.getNavigationModel(webRequestContext.getLocalization());

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(CAPACITY);
    builder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
    builder.append("<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">");
    writeSitemapItemsXml(model.getItems(), builder, webRequestContext.getBaseUrl());
    builder.append("</urlset>");

    return builder.toString();
}

So to extend it, I create a class that extends this controller class and am overriding the method
public class CustomSiteMapXmlController extends SiteMapXmlController{
    
    //private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SiteMapXmlController.class);
    private static final int CAPACITY = 16384;
    
    
    private final NavigationProvider navigationProvider;
    private final WebRequestContext webRequestContext;
    
    
    @Autowired
    public CustomSiteMapXmlController(WebRequestContext webRequestContext, NavigationProvider navigationProvider,
            Markup markup) {
        super(webRequestContext, navigationProvider, markup);
        this.navigationProvider = navigationProvider;
        this.webRequestContext = webRequestContext;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    

    @Override
    /**
     * This method is supposed to be extended in order to change the default behavior.
     */
    public String getXmlSitemap() throws NavigationProviderException {
        SitemapItem model = navigationProvider.getNavigationModel(webRequestContext.getLocalization());

        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(CAPACITY);
        builder.append("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>");
        builder.append("<urlset xmlns=\"http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9\">");
        builder.append("<custom>This is custom sitemap</custom>");
        //writeSitemapItemsXml(model.getItems(), builder, webRequestContext.getBaseUrl());
        builder.append("</urlset>");

        return builder.toString();
    }
}

But when I hit the url/sitemap.xml now, it still goes to the default sitemap implementation.
When I create the Custom Sitemap Controller class as @Controller, and add a new method with custom request mapping, and call the getXmlSitemap(), it works perfectly fine. But I want to override the default functionality.
Am I missing something here with extending the method? Is it possible to override the default Sitemap functionality like this or Is it only possible to extend the method if we are trying to create a custom request mapping?
